# Removing multiple return from method

Tags: java

I need to validate based on some condition if if failed then I need to return from that block. Please find below code

```
private String validate() {
    String test = validateName();

    if (!test.isEmpty()) {
        return test;
    }

    test = validateAddress();

    if (!test.isEmpty()) {
        return test;
    }

    test = validateInformation();

    if (!test.isEmpty()) {
        return test;
    }

    test = validateSSN();

    if (!test.isEmpty()) {
        return test;
    }

    test = validateSecurityDetails();

    if (!test.isEmpty()) {
        return test;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

The above code is working fine. In this code I have used multiple return that I need to avoid. What is the other best way to do that

Comment: I would like to downvote your post but unfortunately my reputation points are too low...

Comment: @JuhaP: You can still give suggestions why and thus help improve the quality of the post. Don't downvote without giving a hint!

Comment: Why do you need to avoid multiple returns? What do the validate method you're calling actually look like?

Comment: "I have used multiple return that I need to avoid" -- Firstly, why? Secondly, it's easy to use a temporary variable which you set in multiple places and finally return. Still, I don't thing this is a good place to ask, because you don't ask for a code review but rather how to implement some (arbitrary) requirement. This is probably better off at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I've downvoted, as this isn't really a code review request. I will make a comment or two, though.
1) Like forsvarir, I'd like to know why you have to avoid multiple returns.
2) It would be more natural in Java for the validate... methods to return boolean.
  (And then you could simply return validateName() && validateAddress()....)

Answer (score 1):

What is the result of `validate....` ? If it is an error message, why whould skip validating the rest? Better to join them in a `List`.

```
List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
String nameError = validateName();
if (!nameError.isEmpty()) {
    errors.add(nameError)
}

String addressError = validateAddress();
if (!addressError.isEmpty()) {
    errors.add(addressError)
}

return errors;
```

Answer (score 1):

*In general* there could be parallel validation, maybe local at the fields.
And indeed, instead of a code review here, it might be worth researching other validations. Like field annotations. However you probably already went this road.

Like collecting more than one error as already answered.

But to the question.

You have some `UnaryOperator<String>` with type signature `String()`.

A solution with some **ugliness** would be:

```
private String validate() {
    UnaryOpterator<String>[] tests = {
        this::validateName, this::validateAddress,
        this::validateInformation, ...
    };
    for (UnaryOpterator<String> test : tests) {
        if (!test.isEmpty()) {
            return test;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This could also be done with a Stream too, saving a bit.

Using `null` as *no error*, might be considered bad style. One would need to refactor much, but it would allow:

```
private Optional<String> validate() {
    return Optional.empty()
        .orElseGet(this::validateName)
        .orElseGet(this::validateAddress)
        .orElseGet(this::validateInformation) ...;
}
```

It eliminates null pointer worries.

This already looks sensible.